# No toma el valor del "event value" del React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Tengo un problema. Estoy haciendo un formulario cuya finalidad es editar / modificar la información del paciente. El problema es: Cuando cambio el género en el combo (react select [todos son react select]) y elijo otro género lo cambia, así como en el combo de "ocupaciones" (*), entidad federativa (*) y municipio (este ultimo no tengo ningún problema, pasa bien los datos a la API y todo).

(*) Pero, cuando cambio el valor / elijo otro renglón de información se queda con los mismos IDs que ya venían de la consulta al cargar los datos del formulario, es decir, que al guardar / pasar los datos a la API -no- toma en cuenta / no respeta el event.value que se le asigna a la const asignada.

Francamente no entiendo que está pasando... Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme, como dato dejo lo siguiente: La API está hecha en PHP nativo y funciona; y si llena los combos con la información de las consultas. He tratado en poner todo en un "useffect" para alimentar / llenar los combos de: géneros, ocupaciones y entidades federativas (el mismo problema) y también he puesto (como lo podrán ver) en varios useffect para cargar c/u de los combos y con el mismo resultado / problema. A continuación, pongo todo el código del formulario. No soy un experto en ReactJs, tengo 3 meses en esta librería. Gracias y saludos.

Código:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select"; 
 



const Idpaso = [{Id_entidad_fed:""}];
const genero_pasardatos=[{Id_genero:"", nomgen:""}];
const municipios_pasardatos=[{Idmun:"", nommun:""}]; 
const ocupaciones_pasardatos=[{Idocup:"", nomespe:""}];
 

const Editarpaciente = () => {   
    const { id } = useParams(); 
     

    useEffect(() => {
     const datosuser={Id_usuario:sessionStorage.getItem("Iduser")};   
                
     fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Usuarios/SP_Verificar_DerechoXIDUsuario.php",{
       method:"POST",
       body:JSON.stringify(datosuser)
      })
       .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
       .then((datosRespuesta)=>{  
         let Acceso =  datosRespuesta[0]["Cat_paciente"]; 
         switch (Acceso) {
                 case "1":
                        try {
                             ///----Ver el Paciente X ID al que se le va modificar
                             fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Paciente/SP_Ver_paciente_XID.php"+"?Id="+ id)
                             .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
                             .then((respuesta)=>{  
                                 nombrepersonalchange(respuesta[0].Nombre_pas);
                                 segnombrepersonalchange(respuesta[0].Segundo_nom);   
                                 apellidpatpersonalchange(respuesta[0].Apellido_pat);
                                 apellidmatpersonalchange(respuesta[0].Apellido_mat);
                                 fechanaconochange(respuesta[0].Fecha_nac);
                                 setIdOcupaciones(respuesta[0].Id_ocupacion);
                                 setNomOcupaciones(respuesta[0].Nom_ocup);  
                                 setIdentfed(respuesta[0].Id_entidad_fed);//--Id entfed
                                 nomentchange(respuesta[0].Nombre);//--nombre de la entidad federativa
                                 setIdmun(respuesta[0].Id_mun);//--Id mun
                                 nommunchange(respuesta[0].Nom_mun);
                                 Notaschange(respuesta[0].Notas);
                                 telefonochange(respuesta[0].Tel);
                                 celularonochange(respuesta[0].Cel);
                                 emailonochange(respuesta[0].email);
                                 Dironochange(respuesta[0].Dir); 
                                 setIdgenros(respuesta[0].Id_genero);//--Id género
                                 nomgenonochange(respuesta[0].Nom_genero);  
                              }
                             )
                             .catch(console.log)  
                        } catch (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                        }  
                break;

                case "0":
                    alert("No tiene derecho a la página.");
                    window.location.href = "/Home";
                break;                         
     
                case null: 
                    alert("No tiene derecho a la página.");
                    window.location.href = "/Home";                                                                               
                break;
         }           
        }
        )
         .catch(console.log)
      }, []);   
      const[Id_genero, setIdgenros]=useState(""); 
      genero_pasardatos.Id_genero=Id_genero;
      
      const [Identfed, setIdentfed]=useState("");
      //entidad_pasardatos.Ident=Identfed;
      Idpaso.Id_entidad_fed=Identfed;
       
      const[Idmun, setIdmun]=useState("");
      municipios_pasardatos.Idmun=Idmun;  
      
      const[Id_ocupacion, setIdOcupaciones]=useState("");
      ocupaciones_pasardatos.Idocup=Id_ocupacion;
      const[nomocuaciones, setNomOcupaciones]=useState(""); 
      const[txtnombpaciente, nombrepersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtsegundonombpaciente, segnombrepersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtApellidopat, apellidpatpersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtApellidomat, apellidmatpersonalchange]=useState(""); 
      const[txtDir, Dironochange]=useState("");
      const[txtTel, telefonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtCelular, celularonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtEmail, emailonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtFechaNac, fechanaconochange]=useState("");
      const[txtnomgen, nomgenonochange]=useState(""); //--
      const[txtnommun, nommunchange]=useState("");//-  
      const[txtnoment, nomentchange]=useState("");//-
      const[txtNotas, Notaschange]=useState("");


      useEffect(() => {
          //------------------------------ 
                     ///------------Géneros---------------**
                     fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Genero/SP_Ver_Genero_Lista.php")
                     .then(respuesta2=>respuesta2.json())
                     .then((respuesta2)=>{           
                      setgenros(respuesta2); 
                    } 
                 )
                  .catch(console.log) 

   }, []); 

   const[generos, setgenros]=useState([]); 

      const handleSelectChangeGeneros= (event)=>{          
            genero_pasardatos.Id_genero=null; //--se limpia antes de pasar ID de cambio
            //--para que se evite la duplicidad en el arreglo de ID´s 
            genero_pasardatos.Id_genero=event.value;
            console.log(genero_pasardatos);  
          
      } 

      useEffect(() => {
                 ////----------------------------------****** 
                          ///------------Ocupaciones---------------**
                          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Ocupacion/SP_Ver_Lista_Ocupaciones.php")
                          .then(respuesta4=>respuesta4.json())
                          .then((respuesta4)=>{           
                                setOcupaciones(respuesta4); 
                              } 
                           )
                            .catch(console.log) 
                          ////----------------------------------****** 

     }, []); 
    
     const[ocuaciones, setOcupaciones]=useState([]); 
    
    const handleSelectChangeOcupaciones= (event)=>{
           ocupaciones_pasardatos.Idocup=null; 
           ocupaciones_pasardatos.Idocup=event.value; 
           console.log(ocupaciones_pasardatos);
      
    }  


    useEffect(() => {
             
                          ////----------------------------------******
                          ///------------Entidad Federativas---------------**
                          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Entidad%20Federativa/SP_Ver_Lista_Entidades_fed.php")
                          .then(respuesta3=>respuesta3.json())
                          .then((respuesta3)=>{           
                                 setEntidadFede(respuesta3); 
                              } 
                           )
                            .catch(console.log) 

      }, []);  

   const[entidadesfederativas, setEntidadFede]=useState([]);



    const handleSelectChangeEntidadFed= (event)=>{ 
      Idpaso.Id_entidad_fed=null;   
      Idpaso.Id_entidad_fed=event.value;
      console.log(Idpaso);

     try { 
          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Municipio/SP_Ver_Municipio_Lista_XIDentidad.php"+"?Id="+ Idpaso.Id_entidad_fed)
          .then(respuesta5=>respuesta5.json())
          .then((respuesta5)=>{           
                setMunicipios(respuesta5); 
              } 
           )
            .catch(console.log)  

        } catch (error) {
             console.log(error);
        }  
     }

 const[municipios, setMunicipios]=useState([]);

 const handleSelectChangeMunicipios= (event)=>{ 
      municipios_pasardatos.Idmun=null; 
      municipios_pasardatos.Idmun=event.value; 
      console.log(municipios_pasardatos); 
 }


      const enviarDatos=(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault(); 

          const datospaciente={
               Idpersonal:id,
               Nombre:txtnombpaciente, 
               Seg_nom:txtsegundonombpaciente, 
               Apellido_pat:txtApellidopat, 
               Apellido_mat:txtApellidomat,
               Fecha_nac:txtFechaNac, 
               Tel:txtTel,
               Cel:txtCelular,
               email:txtEmail,
               Dir:txtDir,  
               Id_Genero:genero_pasardatos.Id_genero,
               Idocup:ocupaciones_pasardatos.Idocup,
               Identfed:Idpaso.Id_entidad_fed,
               Nota:txtNotas,
               Id_mun:municipios_pasardatos.Idmun, 
               Id_sucursal:sessionStorage.getItem("Id_sucursal"),   
               Id_usuario:sessionStorage.getItem("Iduser")};  

               console.log(datospaciente); 




              
      }

        return ( 
          <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header" align="center">
              Editar Paciente -En sucursal-
          </div>
          <div className="card-body" >
              <form   id="webFrmEditarPaciente" onSubmit={enviarDatos}>  
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">ID:</label>
                               <input type="numeric"   value={id || ''}  name="txtIDpaciente" id="txtIDpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ID del paciente" required readOnly></input>
                          </div>


                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Nombre:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>nombrepersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtnombpaciente || ''}  name="txtnombpaciente" id="txtnombpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal" required ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Segundo Nombre:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>segnombrepersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtsegundonombpaciente || ''}  name="txtsegundonombpaciente" id="txtsegundonombpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal"  ></input>
                          </div>
                           
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Apellido Paterno:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>apellidpatpersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtApellidopat || ''} name="txtApellidopat" id="txtApellidopat" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea apellido paterno" ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Apellido Materno:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>apellidmatpersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtApellidomat || ''}  name="txtApellidomat" id="txtApellidomat" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea apellido materno"  ></input>
                          </div> 

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                               <input type="date" onChange={e=>fechanaconochange(e.target.value)} value={txtFechaNac || ''} name="txtFechaNac" id="txtFechaNac" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"   min="1930-01-01" max="2080-12-31" required></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Género:</label>
                              <Select 
                                 className='search-line'
                                 placeholder={txtnomgen || ''}
                                 options={generos.map(sup=>({label: sup.Nom_genero, value: sup.Id_genero }))}
                                 onChange={handleSelectChangeGeneros}  
                               />
                          </div>  
                          <br></br><br></br> 

                          <div className="form-group">
                                  <label htmlFor="">Ocupación:</label>
                                     <Select 
                                         className='search-line'
                                         placeholder={nomocuaciones || ''}
                                         options={ocuaciones.map(sup3=>({label: sup3.Nom_ocup, value: sup3.Id_ocupacion }))}
                                         onChange={handleSelectChangeOcupaciones}  
                                      />
                         </div>  
                          <br></br><br></br>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Entidad Federativa:</label>
                               <Select 
                                     className='search-line'
                                     placeholder={txtnoment || ''}
                                     options={entidadesfederativas.map(sup2=>({label: sup2.Nombre, value: sup2.ident }))}
                                     onChange={handleSelectChangeEntidadFed}  
                                 />
                          </div>  
                         <br></br><br></br>

                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Municipios que tiene:</label>
                                  <Select 
                                        className='search-line' 
                                        placeholder={txtnommun || ''}
                                        options={municipios.map(sup4=>({label: sup4.Nom_mun, value: sup4.Id_mun }))}
                                        onChange={handleSelectChangeMunicipios} 
                                  />
                        </div>  
                         <br></br><br></br>

                         <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Teléfono:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>telefonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtTel || ''}  name="txtTel" id="txtTel" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación"  ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Celular:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>celularonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtCelular || ''} name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nota de la ocupación" required></input>
                          </div>

                          
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Email:</label>
                               <input type="email" onChange={e=>emailonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtEmail || ''} name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nota de la ocupación" required></input>
                          </div>


                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Dirección:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>Dironochange(e.target.value)} value={txtDir || ''}  name="txtDir" id="txtDir" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación"  ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Notas:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>Notaschange(e.target.value)} value={txtNotas || ''}  name="txtNotas" id="txtNotas" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea Notas del paciente, si las hay."  ></input>
                          </div>

                                <div className="input-group">
                                    <span className="input-group-btn">                                        
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit" aria-label="">Guardar</button>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <Link to={"/listarpacientes"} className="btn btn-danger" type="button" aria-label="">Cancelar</Link>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <Link to={"/listarpacientes"} className="btn btn-warning" type="button" aria-label="" id="btnsalir" >Regresar al Listado</Link>
                                   </span>                                    
                                 </div>                              
                    </form>                             
                </div>                
             </div>
         );
    }
 
export default Editarpaciente;
```

Imágenes de cambio de los valores y del vector que envía a la API al modificar:
Como podrán observar, SI hace los cambios si se elige otro valor, PERO, al enviar / dar click en guardar... Los valores se quedan con los datos que se cargaron al consultar la información (cuando carga el formulario), supongo que debe de ser algo muy "simple" de resolver, pero, ya tengo varios días con esto y ya estoy ciclado en el problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bien, ya arregle mi problema. Espero, que lo siguiente le se de utilidad a cualquiera. Con lo siguiente logré pasar adecuadamente el valor del ID / value del React Select. Saludos a todos y gracias.

*Usando los "const" de cada uno, solo que al asignar el "event.value" lo asigno al "setIdmun" (solo por dar un ejemplo) usando una variable (em este caso valuemunicipio). Entonces, con eso al pasarlo a la API para que la misma pase los campos / parámetros para mi SP.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select"; 
 



 
let valuegenero = null;
let valueetindadfed = null;
let valuemunicipio = null;
let valueocupaciones = null;
 
 

const Editarpaciente = () => {   
    const { id } = useParams(); 
     

    useEffect(() => {
     const datosuser={Id_usuario:sessionStorage.getItem("Iduser")};   
                
     fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Usuarios/SP_Verificar_DerechoXIDUsuario.php",{
       method:"POST",
       body:JSON.stringify(datosuser)
      })
       .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
       .then((datosRespuesta)=>{  
         let Acceso =  datosRespuesta[0]["Cat_paciente"]; 
         switch (Acceso) {
                 case "1":
                        try {
                             ///----Ver el Paciente X ID al que se le va modificar
                             fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Paciente/SP_Ver_paciente_XID.php"+"?Id="+ id)
                             .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
                             .then((respuesta)=>{  
                                 nombrepersonalchange(respuesta[0].Nombre_pas);
                                 segnombrepersonalchange(respuesta[0].Segundo_nom);   
                                 apellidpatpersonalchange(respuesta[0].Apellido_pat);
                                 apellidmatpersonalchange(respuesta[0].Apellido_mat);
                                 fechanaconochange(respuesta[0].Fecha_nac);
                                 setIdOcupaciones(respuesta[0].Id_ocupacion);
                                 setNomOcupaciones(respuesta[0].Nom_ocup);  
                                 setIdentfed(respuesta[0].Id_entidad_fed);//--Id entfed
                                 nomentchange(respuesta[0].Nombre);//--nombre de la entidad federativa
                                 setIdmun(respuesta[0].Id_mun);//--Id mun
                                 nommunchange(respuesta[0].Nom_mun);
                                 Notaschange(respuesta[0].Notas);
                                 telefonochange(respuesta[0].Tel);
                                 celularonochange(respuesta[0].Cel);
                                 emailonochange(respuesta[0].email);
                                 Dironochange(respuesta[0].Dir); 
                                 setIdgenros(respuesta[0].Id_genero);//--Id género
                                 nomgenonochange(respuesta[0].Nom_genero);  
                              }
                             )
                             .catch(console.log)  
                        } catch (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                        }  
                break;

                case "0":
                    alert("No tiene derecho a la página.");
                    window.location.href = "/Home";
                break;                         
     
                case null: 
                    alert("No tiene derecho a la página.");
                    window.location.href = "/Home";                                                                               
                break;
         }           
        }
        )
         .catch(console.log)
      }, []);   
      const[Id_genero, setIdgenros]=useState(""); 
      valuegenero=Id_genero; 
       
      
      const [Identfed, setIdentfed]=useState(""); 
      valueetindadfed=Identfed; 
       
       
      const[Idmun, setIdmun]=useState("");
      valuemunicipio=Idmun;
         
      
      const[Id_ocupacion, setIdOcupaciones]=useState("");
      valueocupaciones=Id_ocupacion;
       

      const[nomocuaciones, setNomOcupaciones]=useState(""); 
      const[txtnombpaciente, nombrepersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtsegundonombpaciente, segnombrepersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtApellidopat, apellidpatpersonalchange]=useState("");
      const[txtApellidomat, apellidmatpersonalchange]=useState(""); 
      const[txtDir, Dironochange]=useState("");
      const[txtTel, telefonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtCelular, celularonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtEmail, emailonochange]=useState("");
      const[txtFechaNac, fechanaconochange]=useState("");
      const[txtnomgen, nomgenonochange]=useState(""); //--
      const[txtnommun, nommunchange]=useState("");//-  
      const[txtnoment, nomentchange]=useState("");//-
      const[txtNotas, Notaschange]=useState("");


      useEffect(() => {
          //------------------------------ 
                     ///------------Géneros---------------**
                     fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Genero/SP_Ver_Genero_Lista.php")
                     .then(respuesta2=>respuesta2.json())
                     .then((respuesta2)=>{           
                      setgenros(respuesta2); 
                    } 
                 )
                  .catch(console.log) 

   }, []); 

   const[generos, setgenros]=useState([]); 
    

      const handleSelectChangeGeneros= (event)=>{  
            valuegenero = event.value;
            setIdgenros(valuegenero);  
      } 

      useEffect(() => {
                 ////----------------------------------****** 
                          ///------------Ocupaciones---------------**
                          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Ocupacion/SP_Ver_Lista_Ocupaciones.php")
                          .then(respuesta4=>respuesta4.json())
                          .then((respuesta4)=>{           
                                setOcupaciones(respuesta4); 
                              } 
                           )
                            .catch(console.log) 
                          ////----------------------------------****** 

     }, []); 
    
     const[ocuaciones, setOcupaciones]=useState([]); 
    
    const handleSelectChangeOcupaciones= (event)=>{ 
           valueocupaciones=event.value;
           setIdOcupaciones(valueocupaciones);
      
    }  


    useEffect(() => {
             
                          ////----------------------------------******
                          ///------------Entidad Federativas---------------**
                          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Entidad%20Federativa/SP_Ver_Lista_Entidades_fed.php")
                          .then(respuesta3=>respuesta3.json())
                          .then((respuesta3)=>{           
                                 setEntidadFede(respuesta3); 
                              } 
                           )
                            .catch(console.log) 

      }, []);  

   const[entidadesfederativas, setEntidadFede]=useState([]);



    const handleSelectChangeEntidadFed= (event)=>{ 
      valueetindadfed=event.value; 
      setIdentfed(valueetindadfed);
       

     try { 
          fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Municipio/SP_Ver_Municipio_Lista_XIDentidad.php"+"?Id="+ valueetindadfed)
          .then(respuesta5=>respuesta5.json())
          .then((respuesta5)=>{           
                setMunicipios(respuesta5); 
              } 
           )
            .catch(console.log)  

        } catch (error) {
             console.log(error);
        }  
     }

 const[municipios, setMunicipios]=useState([]);

 const handleSelectChangeMunicipios= (event)=>{ 
      valuemunicipio=event.value; 
      setIdmun(valuemunicipio); 
 }


      const enviarDatos=(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault(); 

          const datospaciente={
               Idpersonal:id,
               Nombre:txtnombpaciente, 
               Seg_nom:txtsegundonombpaciente, 
               Apellido_pat:txtApellidopat, 
               Apellido_mat:txtApellidomat,
               Fecha_nac:txtFechaNac, 
               Tel:txtTel,
               Cel:txtCelular,
               email:txtEmail,
               Dir:txtDir,  
               Id_Genero:Id_genero,
               Idocup:Id_ocupacion,
               Identfed:Identfed,               
               Id_mun:Idmun, 
               Nota:txtNotas,
               Id_sucursal:sessionStorage.getItem("Id_sucursal"),   
               Id_usuario:sessionStorage.getItem("Iduser")};  

               console.log(datospaciente); 




              
      }

        return ( 
          <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header" align="center">
              Editar Paciente -En sucursal-
          </div>
          <div className="card-body" >
              <form   id="webFrmEditarPaciente" onSubmit={enviarDatos}>  
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">ID:</label>
                               <input type="numeric"   value={id || ''}  name="txtIDpaciente" id="txtIDpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ID del paciente" required readOnly></input>
                          </div>


                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Nombre:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>nombrepersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtnombpaciente || ''}  name="txtnombpaciente" id="txtnombpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal" required ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Segundo Nombre:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>segnombrepersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtsegundonombpaciente || ''}  name="txtsegundonombpaciente" id="txtsegundonombpaciente" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nombre del personal"  ></input>
                          </div>
                           
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Apellido Paterno:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>apellidpatpersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtApellidopat || ''} name="txtApellidopat" id="txtApellidopat" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea apellido paterno" ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Apellido Materno:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>apellidmatpersonalchange(e.target.value)} value={txtApellidomat || ''}  name="txtApellidomat" id="txtApellidomat" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea apellido materno"  ></input>
                          </div> 

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                               <input type="date" onChange={e=>fechanaconochange(e.target.value)} value={txtFechaNac || ''} name="txtFechaNac" id="txtFechaNac" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"   min="1930-01-01" max="2080-12-31" required></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Género:</label>
                              <Select 
                                 className='search-line'
                                 placeholder={txtnomgen || ''}
                                 options={generos.map(sup=>({label: sup.Nom_genero, value: sup.Id_genero }))}
                                 onChange={handleSelectChangeGeneros}  
                               />
                          </div>  
                          <br></br><br></br> 

                          <div className="form-group">
                                  <label htmlFor="">Ocupación:</label>
                                     <Select 
                                         className='search-line'
                                         placeholder={nomocuaciones || ''}
                                         options={ocuaciones.map(sup3=>({label: sup3.Nom_ocup, value: sup3.Id_ocupacion }))}
                                         onChange={handleSelectChangeOcupaciones}  
                                      />
                         </div>  
                          <br></br><br></br>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Entidad Federativa:</label>
                               <Select 
                                     className='search-line'
                                     placeholder={txtnoment || ''}
                                     options={entidadesfederativas.map(sup2=>({label: sup2.Nombre, value: sup2.ident }))}
                                     onChange={handleSelectChangeEntidadFed}  
                                 />
                          </div>  
                         <br></br><br></br>

                         <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="">Municipios que tiene:</label>
                                  <Select 
                                        className='search-line' 
                                        placeholder={txtnommun || ''}
                                        options={municipios.map(sup4=>({label: sup4.Nom_mun, value: sup4.Id_mun }))}
                                        onChange={handleSelectChangeMunicipios} 
                                  />
                        </div>  
                         <br></br><br></br>

                         <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Teléfono:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>telefonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtTel || ''}  name="txtTel" id="txtTel" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación"  ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Celular:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>celularonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtCelular || ''} name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nota de la ocupación" required></input>
                          </div>

                          
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Email:</label>
                               <input type="email" onChange={e=>emailonochange(e.target.value)} value={txtEmail || ''} name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea nota de la ocupación" required></input>
                          </div>


                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Dirección:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>Dironochange(e.target.value)} value={txtDir || ''}  name="txtDir" id="txtDir" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea ocupación"  ></input>
                          </div>

                          <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Notas:</label>
                               <input type="text" onChange={e=>Notaschange(e.target.value)} value={txtNotas || ''}  name="txtNotas" id="txtNotas" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea Notas del paciente, si las hay."  ></input>
                          </div>

                                <div className="input-group">
                                    <span className="input-group-btn">                                        
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit" aria-label="">Guardar</button>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <Link to={"/listarpacientes"} className="btn btn-danger" type="button" aria-label="">Cancelar</Link>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <Link to={"/listarpacientes"} className="btn btn-warning" type="button" aria-label="" id="btnsalir" >Regresar al Listado</Link>
                                   </span>                                    
                                 </div>                              
                    </form>                             
                </div>                
             </div>
         );
    }
 
export default Editarpaciente;
```

Prueba en arreglo con los campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]